# Better Solution to find all classes which inherit from a baseclass (and interface) and return a list not List<System.Type> but List<Interface>

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, type-conversion, activator

Maybe my brain is not working properly and i cant see the forest because of the trees ...

Currently I have a class called `CheckManager` which searches the current assembly for a certain type called `UserControlBaseCheck` which is declared in a separate library.  (this works fine)

I do have a variable *AllChecks* of type `SortedDictionary<IBaseCheck, UserControlBaseCheck>` (and a custom `IComparer` class which know's how to sort `IBaseCheck`).

This variable *AllChecks* is used to populate a `Stack`. The stack is then worked through by a User, once it is depleted, it get's filled again with new instances of all classes inside the `AllChecks` variable. And the whole game starts again.

Currently i solved it this way:

```
//declaration of my container with all checks
private static SortedDictionary<IBaseCheck, UserControlBaseCheck> AllChecks =
        new SortedDictionary<IBaseCheck, UserControlBaseCheck>(new Comparer());

// this is how i call the method to find all classes which inherit from the type
FindDerivedTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), typeof(UserControlBaseCheck));

//this is the definition... it seems to me bit odd that I have to use the Activator 
//and create an instance and cast it to the interface just to do 
//what i want to do... 
//is there any other / easier / better way of doing so?
public static IList<IBaseCheck> FindDerivedTypes(Assembly assembly,Type baseType)
{
      //FYI: until the '.Select' I get a list of type List<System.Type>
      List<IBaseCheck> o = assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t != baseType && baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t))
        .Select(type => Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IBaseCheck)
        .ToList();

      return o;
}
```

i find it odd that I have to create first an instance of the type  just to use/convert it to an interface. Why can't i just do:  `.Select(x=> x as IBaseCheck)` I mean i have already a list with object of type `List<System.Type>` and it seems to me bit overkill what i am doing just to get my list of type  `IBaseCheck` (`List<IBaseCheck>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't I just do: `.Select(x=> x as IBaseCheck)`

Because `x` is an instance of the `System.Type` type, not your `UserControlBaseCheck` type.

It's important to understand that, when you use reflection, you are getting the *metadata* for the types. I.e. you are getting data that describes your types, not the types themselves. The `System.Type` type is one such kind of data. It is a runtime object that describes the types you declare. It is *not* those actual types, and it's definitely not an *instance* of those types.

Consider the trivial code example:

```
namespace ExampleNamespace
{
    class A { }
}
```

There are many different ways of getting the `System.Type` that represents that type:

```
Type type1 = Assembly.GetType("ExampleNamespace.A"),
    type2 = typeof(A),
    type3 = (new A()).GetType();
```

But note that in the above, all three variables wind up with the same instance of `System.Type`. I.e. the instance that describes that type A.

Note also in the last assignment, to the variable `type3`, a new instance of `A` is being created. I.e. you can ask an instance for the information about its own type. But what's returned is not, of course, that instance. It's something completely different: the instance of `System.Type` describing the type of that instance of `A`.

So back to your example…
You're using reflection to search for instances of specific `System.Type` objects. These instances give you enough information to figure out which ones implement some base class (or even an interface, if you wanted). But since you want an actual *instance* of that class, you need to explicitly ask for one.

Just as you can't do this:

```
A a = typeof(A);
```

You also can't do this:

```
IBaseCheck baseCheck = typeof(UserControlBaseCheck);
```

Instead, you need to do this:

```
IBaseCheck baseCheck = new UserControlBaseCheck();
```

And the way that's done via reflection (well, *one* way anyway) is to call the `Activator.CreateInstance()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. That makes sense, I was not thinking of the fact that the Type class just holds some metadata information of the actual class (type). Now everything makes sense.

Comment: *Facepalm*  I confused myself thinking i can get type-information of the own type - if that makes sense ... Basically a list of List<IBaseClass> with type information and not instances. Why did i think that? Hovering over the the List items in Debug mode I expected to see something like IBaseCheck(Check1) instead of System.Type (Namespace.ClassName)  ---  */Facepalm* (I am not sure how to explain it better what I was expecting to see...i think I got to lazy/comfortable developer)